# Proper use of 's?

Tags: grammar

What would be grammatically correct? Would I need to use `'s` after "Supreme Court"?

> ...overruled a prior decision of the Supreme Court, defined in the...

or

> ...overruled a prior decision of the Supreme Court's, defined in the...

...I know I can structure the sentence in a better format as so:

> ...overruled a prior decision made by the Supreme Court, defined in the...

However, I want to know which one from the first two is correct.

Comment: No 's.  Just check at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_overruled_U.S._Supreme_Court_decisions

Answer (score 0):

The complete sentence would've been helpful, but still, here you go:

> ...overruled a prior decision of the Supreme Court, defined in the...

Here you are using *decision **of** the Supreme Court*, so no **'s** required, and the sentence is correct.

> ...overruled a prior decision of the Supreme Court's, defined in
>   the...

Here you are using the same **of**, so the **'s** is unnecessary. If you do want to use the **'s**, you have to remove the **of**, like:

> ...overruled the Supreme Court's prior decision

But as you can see, this changes the meaning of the sentence slightly. It no longer talks about ***a certain decision*** made by the Supreme Court, which was the intention of your original sentence, to begin with.

Comment: There is a real beauty of a subtlety here, which I just realised. The use of the possessive seems to be more "natural" when using a pronoun instead of a proper or common noun. I'll elaborate. Which of these sentences sounds more correct? "That decision of *you* was totally unjust!" vs "That decision of *yours* was totally unjust!". Now compare: "That decision of the referee was totally unjust!" vs "That decision of the referee's was totally unjust!". See what I mean?

Comment: ... It doesn't stop there. I'd say both "That decision of the referee was totally unjust!" & "That decision of the referee's was totally unjust!" are both quite acceptable. But ??'An ally of England's'.